# sum textbox values through loop

Tags: javascript, html

I have created 5 textboxes in html through php loop. Now I want to add the value of that textboxes through javascript. I have tried but it gives me the wrong result. The below is my code..

```
<? for($i=0; $i<5; $i++)
{?>
<input type="text" id="<?=$i;?>" onclick="get(id)" />
<?}?>

function get(x){


        var summ=0;
        for(var a=0; a<5; a++)
        {
            summ=summ+document.getElementById(a).value;

        }
        alert(summ);
    }
```

Comment: If those values are integers try `sum += parseInt(document.getElementById(a).value, 10);`

Comment: @Yuri Tarabanko : if you do it like that it will return Not a Number, since you are converting to Int an "undefined" (the empty fields). Solution is: sum += parseInt(document.getElementById(a).value, 10) || 0;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem might be caused by the fact that an integer is not a valid id for an html element. You should try and name it something like input-1, input-2 ..

Here's a working example.

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="input-1"  />
<input type="text" id="input-2"  />
<input type="text" id="input-3"  />
<input type="text" id="input-4"  />
<input type="text" id="input-5"  />
```

Javascript:

```
var summ = 0;
for(var a=0; a<5; a++) {
    summ += parseInt(document.getElementById("input-" + (a + 1)).value) || 0;

}
alert(summ);
```

I had to add || 0 to the actual calculation, because otherwise the result would have been "Not a Number" since some of the input fields were empty.

(note that in the fiddle below I use console.log instead of alert. So see the result in the console)

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jonigiuro/tXFEf/1/

Comment: sir, i con not understand || 0; what is is the purpose of this

Comment: @Nasir it is just like OR operator. if the first statement is false i.e not a number then it will add `0` as number.

Comment: Mr_Green is right. It's like saying. Is "parseInt(document.getElementById("input-" + (a + 1)).value)" a number? If not, assign it a 0.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are concatenating the numbers as strings. Try parsing them using

```
parseInt(document.getElementById(a).value)
```

Comment: It'll return NaN because of the "undefined" fields. 
summ += parseInt(document.getElementById("input-" + (a + 1)).value) || 0;

Comment: +1, but I would have used `parseFloat`. If all the numbers happen to be whole numbers, the result would be output as a whole number anyway.

Answer (score 0):

How about using jQuery

```
var sum = 0;

$('input').each(function(){
    sum += $(this).val();
})
```

Comment: Not sure the text() method works to get the text in an input. I think .val() is more appropriate.

Comment: text(), works but value will be more semantically correct, thanks.